# Bootstrap - 3 columns full responsive full height intro page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Currently I'm working on a website for a restaurant / hotel / vineyard. There are supposed to be 3 separate websites that I want to connect on one intro page.

I want to create an intro page which fills the full screen, 3 columns side by side, and each column with full height filled with a picture regarding to each site I want to link.

I started to go about it like this:

**Bootstrap Columns:**

```
<div class="row intro-div no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-4 fill-res"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 fill-wein"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 fill-hotel"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fill-hotel{
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-image: url('../images/intro-hotel.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center; 
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

It looks great on my screen and when I change the size of my browser it's responsive, but it changes the section of the picture. For example, if there were a head in the picture, when I use a larger screen, then the head would be cropped on a small screen.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If it is an option, you could try to use responsive images (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images) instead of background images...

Comment: Mh, could help, but the problem is, that people have different screen aspect ratio.. so i can't calculate the image size :-/

Comment: Well, would the use of `background-size:cover` be a solution? http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/Lv6r8tzv/

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez solution should work if you changed the background position to  `background-position: top center`  - http://jsfiddle.net/Lv6r8tzv/1/

Comment: You guy's are awesome! That's it! Works for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an optimized version of the CSS used by [@Alvaro Menendez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2550987/alvaro-men%C3%A9ndez) to avoid repeating properties for similar elements.

**Note:** there is also a slight change of `background-position: top center;` -> hopefully that should do it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row intro-div no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-4 fill fill-res"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 fill fill-wein"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 fill fill-hotel"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, div {height:100%;}
.col-md-4 {
    float:left;
    width:33.333333333%;
    background-size:cover;
}

.fill{
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center; 
    background-color: #000000;    
}

.fill-hotel{
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Monarch_Butterfly_Danaus_plexippus_Vertical_Caterpillar_2000px.jpg');
}
.fill-res {
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Soyuz_TMA-02M_spacecraft_in_a_vertical_position.jpg');
}
.fill-wein {
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/F-14A_VF-24_Vertical_Climb.JPEG');
}
```

**[Updated fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv6r8tzv/2/)**

Comment: Thank you! :-) I just deleted "html, body", cause it didn't work on handy.